# Why are so many questions closed?

Tags: discussion

Why is there so many questions on this stackexchange site closed? I mean far more than usual. Even very high quality discussions are closed.

Doesn't this high number of closed questions with high number of views and good quality of content seem like that the current policy that governs the criteria for appropriate question might be going against nature?

I mean it feels as if lot of questions or discussions are everything surrounding programmer, programming, and need not be objective or seeking definitive answer.

It appears lot of questions are of inquisitive nature seeking insight into other programmers and finding common subjects of interest.

Is it possible for mods to relax a bit? I mean lot of great questions with [closed] tag everywhere doesn't do justice.

This question in itself is a perfect example of what I am talking about and it will be closed. But I think my point is clear.

Comment: this question should be closed or moved to meta.  Sorry, I just couldn't resist :)  But in all honesty, this question is not a good example, because you know full well, it's off topic.  Others just try to ask for information.

Comment: Although this is off topic for programmers.SE, you should give some examples to back up your theory. I'm talking about a list of "good" questions without an answer (or even comments) that were closed. Most of the time (even if the question is off topic) admins tends to close the question after it receives some kind of response from community. They don't close it immediately.

Comment: it is exactly my point, there should be off-topic tags to discuss misc. questions that is suited for programmer audience. There's plenty of it just spend some extra time reading questions on here and like you said, this is offtopic, so why are you asking me for examples? again this type of relentless search for objectivity in subjective topics is exactly what causes the problem I am highlighting. I don't know what meta nor do I care since I hardly have checked it.

Comment: There are a great many questions posted here that aren't appropriate for this site. Without examples, we can only guess at exactly which questions you're asking about. If you're asking about all off-topic questions, the answer is simple: they were closed because they're off topic. This isn't an open-ended forum for shooting the breeze, it's a Q&A site aimed at a specific topic. Meta is a parallel Q&A site dedicated to questions about the Programmers site, including yours. You'll find a link to the meta site at the top of this page.

Comment: I found the closing of this question simply ridiculous: it seems mods don't like to accept discussions about themselves.

I understand it is not "in topic", but it should have been *migrated*  to a proper site, not *closed*.

Comment: @Caleb, yes I understand Q&A, but questions off topic would be like "Does God hate bad programmers?" vs. "How many monitors do you use for programming". There's only one truly offtopic question and the other is of value to programmers, via concensus or polling or simply acquiring inputs from other programmers. The latter question I found was closed.

Comment: @KimJongWoo so basically you're mad because they closed your question which was off topic because it was too broad? The FAQ is here for a reason... And I repeat, admins don't shoot down instantly off topic questions (usually they allow some discussion and the close it when it becomes too big of a mess). If you don't like it you're not obligated to post questions here, you can find other sites that will accept that kind of questions.

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia admins didn't close this question, users did with closing votes.

Comment: This question reminds me of the Guardian's "Comment is Free" section; the fastest way to get a comment moderated out of existence there is to question the moderation policy!

Comment: @ChristianP: That doesn't change the substance: I talked about "mods" not "admins", where *mods* = "users with moderator priviledge".

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia sorry, I didn't realize the difference (I though that you meant admin == mods).

Comment: @Christian P, oh yes I am hopping mad. </sarcasm> No, there are questions that are not really off-topic but I see it as closed, so I am just raising my voice. It must be that anyone raising contrarian views must be hopping mad, then it's just another sign of herd mentality.

Comment: @ChristianP I just have differing opinions and I hardly think that is grounds for stop asking question, again your assuming that I dislike this site because my question has been closed, but that's probably how you would react in that situation, I simply don't bother if my questions are closed but the fact there are good questions that are relevant to the realm of programming that has been closed, and I feel that it would be more efficient to just have off-topic tags or section dedicated for programming related off-topic questions.

Comment: @Caleb, again I have to make clear differentiation between "off-topic" questions that have pertinence to programming/programmers and "off-topic" questions that have no relevance to the art of programming and of those entities that are involved in the latter. Again, my concern is not with this question in particular being closed but just do a search for `closed` questions and you will see what I mean. Thank you and this is all I will have to say, and I hope that my proposal for some solution to off-topic tag pretaining to programmers and programming is noted, instead of [closed].

Comment: @KimJongWoo There's an appropriate forum for making those kinds of suggestions in a constructive manner, and that forum is the [meta] site. Don't expect people here to take your feedback seriously if you can't be bothered to express it appropriately.

Comment: @KimJongWoo don't assume that you know anything about me. This site suggest that you behave in professional manners but... I will stop because I have spent already too much of my time on this discussion which leads no where.

Comment: @Caleb yes so if I knew that meta existed I would've posted there. Again closing instead of moving it there in itself is an inappropriate response, so how can I seriously be expected to express myself when I am not given a chance to in the first place? closing it simply ends any further discussion instead of moving the question to the appropriate place. Having said that now I know where future suggestions will go to, but I find myself too busy at the moment to create a question there now or any further comments regarding this question.

Comment: @ChristianP I think it's ironic you are concerned with professional manners since you've made personal ad hominem assumption based reasoning to arrive at the notion that I must have been mad to have raised this said question which I calmly explained that is not the issue at all. Rather it's the exact attitude that you displayed that I thought needed to be addressed hence further comments. Yes please do stop, your unprofessional comments do not bring any insight into the situation.

Comment: @KimJongWoo My unprofessional comments? "...I don't know what meta nor do I care..." - this is your comment when I asked you to back up your question with some examples so that we can discuss about them. And you admittedly posted this question even though you knew that it is off topic.

Comment: Don't feed the trolls!

Comment: @MarkBannister If you browse meta, I think you'll find we're pretty open about the moderation process and our decision-making no matter the complaint. Questioning the moderation process doesn't get "moderated out of existence" around here.

Comment: @AnnaLear: Sorry, I wasn't intending to imply that you would moderate a question out of existence, merely for questioning the moderation process. Rather, I saw a parallel between what happens on CiF re: moderation, and the quick closure of a question on Programmers asking why so many questions were closed on Programmers. (And now it has been migrated instead, so the parallel is no longer applicable.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [On discussions and why they don't make good questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6742/on-discussions-and-why-they-dont-make-good-questions)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question isn't a great example since it's not a conceptual software development question but rather a question about the site itself.

That said, now that it's in the right place (on meta), let's talk about the issue you bring up. It would be helpful if you pointed to some questions you specifically think should not have been closed, but in the absence of examples, we can still talk about the general case.

One of the main features of Stack Exchange is that it's high signal and low noise. Leaving questions that are off-topic or don't fit the Q&A model well (e.g. discussion-oriented threads rather than questions that invite explanations) would contribute to noise and dilute the signal.

We've had several discussions about what to do with interesting but off-topic questions and the general result is that Programmers.SE doesn't have to cover everything. There are other sites such as Reddit or Quora that have different policies and philosophies and that might be more welcoming of some of the questions we end up rejecting here.

Here are some links to the previous discussions:

- [Are you fed up with all the frustration that come here on meta?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1895/are-you-fed-up-with-all-the-frustration-that-come-here-on-meta) ([Jeff's answer](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1895/are-you-fed-up-with-all-the-frustration-that-come-here-on-meta/1896#1896) in particular)
- [Offtopic posts - Can they be moved rather than closed?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2304/offtopic-posts-can-they-be-moved-rather-than-closed) / [Should there be another stackexchange site for programmers?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/should-there-be-another-stackexchange-site-for-programmers/)
- [How to reconcile guidelines, community opinion and moderation](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2131/how-to-reconcile-guidelines-community-opinion-and-moderation/) ([Mark's answer](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2131/how-to-reconcile-guidelines-community-opinion-and-moderation/2173#2173) contains some analysis of our closed questions over the last couple of months)

Beyond this, I think we need some specifics from you. Which questions do you think were wrongly closed? What topics do you think should be allowed that currently aren't?

Comment: One closing criterium that I think should not apply to programmers.SE is the "single correct answer" one - and that seems to account for a *lot* of closed questions (example: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/123293). programmers.SE is at heart not about simple, factual questions - exactly the reason it was split off from SO. Insisting that any question that doesn't have a single, objectively correct answer be closed is IMO totally nonsensical. You could just as well close down programmers.SE completely.

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer that question, not being a mod.

I can say that, in my opinion, P.SE is for potentially open-ended questions relating to the programmer life, work, and career.

I suspect what OP is referring to are some of the *useful* questions with lots of votes and answers that wound up closed.

Comment: Mods aren't the only people closing or voting to close questions.

Answer (score -1):

My suspicion:

- The rules are being interpreted too strictly.
- There is a reluctance to re-open a discussion, when someone's "preferred" answer is dominant in an older question.