# is there any stackexchange subdomain that I can ask opinion based questions?

Tags: support, feature-request

Some time I have some question that are opinion based, but I need to know what good programmers think what is better to do on that situation.

So is there any stackexchange subdomain that I can ask opinion based questions !?

Comment: ["We already tried supporting those questions, we even gave them their own site. Sadly, it didn't work out..."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200144/165773)

Comment: I'd suggest giving [On discussions and why they don't make good questions](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6742/40980) and [Why was my question closed as primarily opinion-based?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6491/40980) a read for background on why the answer is 'no'.  Opinion based questions work against the Q&A framework that Stack Exchange has as part of its guiding principles.

Comment: Questions can not be discussion based, but discussions can be part of a community. What I am suggesting here is there should a new button besides `Ask Question` which would be `Start a new discussion`. It will not be result oriented, but can be voted up or down based on the information provided by the user.

Comment: @FaizanRabbani this is already available. Just click [Stack Exchange button aka multi-collider](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/stackexchange-button/info) and then, click the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) link to the right of "Programmers"

Answer (score 2):

As two of the comments mention, no, there isn't a site to ask opinion based questions. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167516/how-can-i-encourage-stack-overflow-to-rein-in-the-subjective-vigilantes/200144#200144), [here](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6742/on-discussions-and-why-they-dont-make-good-questions), and [here](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6491#6491) for more information on that. However, Stack Exchange does have a [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) where these discussions can happen. An example of one chat room would be the [Programmers main chat room, The Whiteboard](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard).