# How can I improve my question?

Tags: discussion

A [question of mine](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/349011/how-can-i-effectively-learn-risky-techniques-algorithms) was put on hold as asking for career / education advice. I obviously didn't see it that way (otherwise I wouldn't have asked it), and can see the usefulness of the question (I imagine it's something all software engineers encounter at some time or another). The question also has a few upvotes and downvotes, giving it a 0 score. What can I do to improve it?

ETA: Add a screenshot of the now-deleted question

[image: deleted post]

Comment: Sadly the question is no longer available. It has been removed. If you had a copy and you wouldn't mind to quote it from this question, maybe the community could help you out here.

Comment: @Laiv screenshot added

Comment: the best you can do right now is training and get practice. A teacher told me once "the doubts comes only after studying.". More concrete questions will come to mind only if you start working on the subject. Pick one of the techniques you want to learn and get practice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question cannot be improved to the point of being on-topic. The crux of the issue is this:

> How can I learn those new, risky things without opening myself up to
>   bad things as a result of my inexperience?

You are asking "how do I learn something?" which is pretty much in the center of the "education" off-topic close reason.

The "education" part of "education and career advice" is not restricted to picking a degree program, or what class to take. Asking how to learn something, whether open-ended or how to deal with difficulties of a particular topic, is still education.

These are great questions to ask - just not on this site. I have mentored many junior developers and even spoken with teenagers looking to get into computer science. I have had many discussions that ended well - but [discussions are off-topic here](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6742/). That is a big part of why education questions are also off-topic: they encourage discussion, not focused Q&A.