# Why was my question about 'outsourcing' closed and downvoted, while others like it upvoted and not closed?

Tags: discussion

My question:

[Are developers in the 3rd world really just as competent?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/352662/) (10k link)

Closed as "opinion-based", downoved as "off-topic".

Similar example: 12 answers, 15 upvotes (just as "off-topic" and "opinion-based"):

[Is outsourcing code more expensive in the long term? Does it harm code quality?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/28110/is-outsourcing-code-more-expensive-in-the-long-term-does-it-harm-code-quality)

(The difference from my question is that mine was about locating the whole division/company in India, etc. rather than putting managers in the U.S. and developers in India, and why companies don't do that *en masse*)

This double standard clearly shows that the mods are wrong.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-windows/info

Comment: Possible duplicate of [On discussions and why they don't make good questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6742/on-discussions-and-why-they-dont-make-good-questions)

Answer (score 6):

The question you asked comes across as a rant against certain ethnic groups or nationalities. *That is my impression and others may disagree*.

The other question you linked takes a more neutral approach and rather than comparing the competencies of developers on two different continents. It approaches the topic from a software engineering approach - comparing cost and risk.

That being said, the other question is borderline and did contain some opinion-based language which I just removed. As it is, I believe it is too broad as I could write a whole book on the topic, citing case studies of various organizations that went through the process of outsourcing and sometimes bringing development back on-shore. I just cast a close vote for being too broad.

Comment: `rant against certain ethnic groups or nationalities` not at all. I only mentioned India, because I've heard concrete numbers about their dev closts and because it's (kind of) English-speaking.

Comment: `That is my impression and others may disagree.` Still, it is not an objectively answerable question. I voted to close _both_ questions.

Answer (score 4):

That question was asked nearly **7 years** ago, when the site scope was different.

I just cast a close vote as you are correct, it should be closed.