# Why is the question "Is it a bad design for a programming language to allow spaces in identifiers" primarily opinion based?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I was checking the "top questions of week" and I just saw the following question was put on hold with the reason "primarily opinion based":

[Is it a bad design for a programming language to allow spaces in identifiers?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/401594/is-it-a-bad-design-for-a-programming-language-to-allow-spaces-in-identifiers)

This specifically made me thing "hey, this is wrongly flagged" in the sense that there could be technical and usability/good practices reasons that would make allowing spaces a bad idea.

Even though the answers should not be a criteria for the quality of a question, the current answers it has indicates that there are indeed good reasons for a programming language to allow spaces in identifiers.

I understand that good/bad design and good/bad practices are subjective. But subjectivity does not mean "primarily opinion based" or "anything goes". If anything, many software engineering practices are "experienced advice". From the [help center](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask):

> **Some subjective questions are allowed, but “subjective” does not mean “anything goes”. All subjective questions are expected to be constructive. What does that mean? Constructive subjective questions:**
>
> - inspire answers that explain “why” and “how”
>
>   - tend to have long, not short, answers
>   - have a constructive, fair, and impartial tone
>   - invite sharing experiences over opinions
>   - insist that opinion be backed up with facts and references
>   - are more than just mindless social fun

On the other side, this question was put on hold by members with high reputation. So this is possibly an indication that I do not have a correct understanding of what the subjectivity vs opinion based line is.

---

**With all that being said, I ask the following questions:**

- Was this question correctly flagged?
- If so, could anyone explain, in the lenses of this question, the reasoning behind and why such questions should not be allowed on the Software Engineering Stack Exchange?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [On discussions and why they don't make good questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6742/on-discussions-and-why-they-dont-make-good-questions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's correctly flagged and closed.

I see three major problems with the question:

- There's no way to discern what "bad" means. Design is already a subjective subject. What does it mean for a design of a programming language to be bad? Hard to read? Hard to write? Hard to parse, interpret, or compile? Focusing on all three is not really feasible since what's best (again - also subjective) may also not be the best consideration for writing tools for the language.
- It's not about a problem. There's no context for what the problem actually is and what research has already been done towards possible solutions and why those solutions may not be good for the context.
- It's a pros and cons question, which tends to attract a lot of opinionated answers. It's incredibly difficult to write a comprehensive answer to such questions, and without a comprehensive answer, it's hard for people (the asker or others) to judge an answer on how good it is for solving the problem. Instead, the result is often a lot of answers and it turns into a popularity contest.

Comment: I have just read in the help center `Moderators can delete any question, and users with sufficient reputation can cast delete votes on closed questions. It takes 3 votes, minimum, to delete a closed question`. With that and your answer, I now understand that the closing a question with the "primarily opinion based" is the way of this website to say "Hey! There is no objective answer to that!" and that does not necessarily mean that the answer will be deleted from the site (as in, if the another person asks the same thing, the person will find that it is opinion based).

Comment: @Albuquerque That's right. I don't see a reason to delete the question, but it definitely doesn't represent a question that's a good fit for this format. Not every question can fit well into the Q&A format here, unfortunately. Closure is a good signal that the question doesn't fit our rules or format, but doesn't necessarily lead to deletion if there's some value in the question and answers.