# Why was this question downvoted?

Tags: discussion

[Here's a link to a question I just posted.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/425245/why-would-you-ever-want-wet-code)

I wanted to understand the trade-off between WET vs DRY code better so I wrote a question about how I've never understood the WET approach to coding. The question got a score of -2 almost immediately. Why? Is the question too subjective? I'm not trying to be arrogant, I just genuinely want to know what I did wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [On discussions and why they don't make good questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6742/on-discussions-and-why-they-dont-make-good-questions)

Answer (score 8):

It's probably been down-voted for the reason that you've identified: you want to start a discussion. The question-and-answer format of Stack Exchange isn't good for a general discussion. Questions do best when they are focused on a specific problem.

Comment: I see. I guess I had misunderstood the purpose of the site. I though SE was more related to discussion about coding, rather than trying to solving specific problems.

Comment: @JensB Our [help center](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) defines our scope. Generally speaking, we're focused on the non-coding aspects of software development: requirements, architecture and design, quality assurance, configuration management, build and release, project management, and process. Other than that, we have similar guidelines as Stack Overflow as to what makes a good question.

Comment: @JensB: Thomas is surely correct, especially for this particular question. However, I think this is only half of the story. According to my observation, it has become hard to ask a question on this site without getting at least one or two downvotes for it (often without any indication why the downvoter does not like the question). IMHO this is a sign for a missing consensus in the community on how to draw the line between "good subjective" and "bad subjective" questions. So as long as a question gets as least as many upvotes as downvotes, I would not bother about the downvotes.