# Do we need a new Off-Topic site?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Offtopic posts - Can they be moved rather than closed?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2304/offtopic-posts-can-they-be-moved-rather-than-closed)
>   [Are you fed up with all the frustration that come here on meta?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1895/are-you-fed-up-with-all-the-frustration-that-come-here-on-meta)
>   [Should there be another stackexchange site for programmers?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/should-there-be-another-stackexchange-site-for-programmers)

Back in the day, the Programmers site was initially created as the Off-Topic site for Stackoverflow. Many of the [most interesting and most favorited questions](http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/query/60785/top-40-closed-questions-most-favorited) form early in this site's life have now been closed as subjective or not constructive.

I understand why the questions have been closed. While I may disagree with closing many of them, that is not what I am arguing for. What I am suggesting is that there needs to be a new site in the stackExhange network specifically for interesting programming questions that are subjective. I know that the theory is that the SO engine doesn't work well for subjective questions, but the evidence shows that there is an audience that enjoys them.

Comment: Well, given that we tried this with Programmers and it was clearly failing, I can't see it being tried again. The Stack Exchange model doesn't work for this type of question. We learnt that the hard way.

Comment: `What I am suggesting is that there needs to be a new site in the stackExhange network specifically for interesting programming questions that are subjective` I fail to see why you chose to post your suggestion on Meta P.SE, instead of creating an Area51 proposal. If you really think there's an audience, go for it...

Answer (score 5):

I think the results from the Programmers “off-topic” experiment showed that off-topic questions can't be bucketed together by the singluar fact that they are off-topic.